# What is the maximum number of shuffles required for the cards to return to their original position?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, permutation-cycles

> > A pack of 13 distinct cards is shuffled in some particular manner and then repeatedly in exactly the same manner. What is the maximum number of shuffles required for cards to return to their original position.

I don't know how to start with this problem. I've never come across such problems in past. Any hint will be appreciated.

**This problem is in the book Pathfinder for Olympiad Mathematics**

**Given Answer : 60**

Comment: you are applying a permutation to the set $\{1,2,\dots,13\}$. If you know some group theory then this problem is equivalent to finding the largest possible order of an element in $S_{13}$, you can consider the cycle representation of such permutations. The order is equal to the least common multiple of the cycle lengths. Thus the problem is equivalent to finding the max value of the lcm of some positive integers whose sum is $13$. It is $60$ with $(4,3,5)$

Comment: In my opinion, this problem cries for using the Computer, only for assistance.  That is, write a computer program, in something like Java or C, that constructs each possible *shuffle*, which obviously represents some permutation of $\{1.2.\cdots, 13\}.$  It seems to me that there are $(13)!$ such permutations.  Then, for each permutation, have the computer program, apply the permutation repeatedly, until the original ordering is restored.  Then, examine those permutations that take the maximum # of applications (i.e. *shuffles*).

Comment: Actually I'm In class 12th right now group theory is new concept to me. Btw thanks.

Comment: The comment of @Onir is very interesting, and somewhat embarrassing, given my previous comment.  My comment, reflects that I have virtually no knowledge of Group Theory.

Comment: Well you don't really need to know group theory. All you need to do is show that permutations can be represented as a bunch of cycles of the form $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ (possibly of size $1$) such that the permutation sends each element to the next element of its corresponding cycle. And then you have to show that if you apply the permutation $m$ times where $m$ is a multiple of all the cycle lengths then no element moves. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation

Comment: If I understand Onir's answer, what he is alleging is that if you try to form different solutions to $x_1 + \cdots + x_k = 13$, where $x_1, \cdots, x_k \in \Bbb{Z^+}$, and $k \leq 13$, then the largest lcm of $\{x_1, \cdots, x_k\}$ will be $(60)$.  This *seems* right to me, because I just experimented with $x_1 = 7$, and I could not construct $x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_k$ such that the lcm of $\{7, x_2, \cdots, x_k\}$ was larger than $(60)$.

Comment: yes exactly, the problem is equivalent to maximizing the lcm to solutions of that equation.

Comment: See for example this similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581820/find-an-element-of-largest-order-in-the-symmetric-group-s-10/1581824#1581824

Comment: @Asinomás Actually I wanted to understand question. What we are actually doing in $4$ cycles. Is it like first I shuffle only $1$ card, then $3$ cards, then $4$ cards, and $5$ cards. Is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in mathematical terms, the shuffle is basically a permutation. And a permutation consists of disjoint cycles. So all the problem is asking is the maximum lowest common multiple of the lengths of the cycles, where the sum of the lengths is $13$.

(e.g. a permutation sending $123456$ to $364512$ has cycles: $(1, 3, 4, 5), (2, 6)$)

When there are $2$ cycles, the greatest LCM can be $6*7 = 42$

When there are $3$ cycles, let the minimum length be $a$. Then $a \leq 4$. Take cases and check that the maximum is achieved when the lengths are $1, 5, 7$ and the LCM is $35$.

When there are $4$ cycles, the maximum is achieved when the lengths are $1, 3, 4, 5$ and the LCM is $60$.

Beyond 4 cycles, it is easy to see that no permutation gives LCM more than $60$. Thus $60$ is the answer.

Comment: Actually I wanted to understand question. What we are actually doing in $4$ cycles. Is it like first I shuffle only $1$ card, then $3$ cards, then $4$ cards, and $5$ cards. Is it so?

Comment: You are shuffling the whole deck, i.e., suppose you have the deck 1234 and a shuffle sends it to 2431 then the first card goes to the end, second to the first, third as it is and fourth to the second. Repeating the shuffle gives 4132 and then 1234 back again.